# counting total number of tcp sockets with non-empty SNDBUF on a linux machine

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, kernel

is there a way for a C program on a linux server to count total number of tcp sockets with non-empty SNDBUF, that is non-empty pipe, or in other words, when data transfer is in progress. Obviously this would have to be counted at an "instance"... Good approximation of such number would be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/proc/net/tcp` file contains a list of all open TCP sockets, and shows the send and receive queues. Finding official documentation on the format of this file [is somewhat tricky](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0409.1/2166.html), but luckily it's somewhat self-explanatory.

Comment: what is the good practice of reading from `/proc/net/tcp`? Is it fopen()->looped fgets()->fclose() sequence every time I wish access the list? Or, buffered reading with fread() would be more efficient?